# Jquery event listener on change unbinding from select box when page returns validation errors from server

Tags: jquery

Here's is an example of my code below. The change listener works all the way up to when a validation error is returns. I've console logged in container updated and can see it firing when returning but jquery doesn't want to re-bind to that element.

If I place that function in the console it does however rebind. I've searched through stack, tested and haven't come up with anything on why this is happening.

```
(function() {

 $("#tab_1").on("container-updated", function() {

   $("#tab_1 select[name='model.doctypeCategory.id']").on("change", function() {

     console.log("Re-bound to element");

 });

}

})();
```

Comment: Not enough known here. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You need to bind events to dynamically added elements? If so use event delegations. There are about thousands of questions on this site alone to help you do it.

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for your comments. I just figured out what I had thought was a jQuery problem. There ended up being a snippet of code which was checking the page for validation error classes that had a return in it which is why it wasn't rebinding to that element. Thank you!